# kotlin-runtime.jar non-existent location

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

i'm currently try to run a simple `Kotlin` Program in `IntelliJ IDEA` . when i run a Hello World sample from this [tutorial](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started.html) page i got this errors and this warnings :

```
Warning:Kotlin: Classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-runtime.jar
Warning:Kotlin: Classpath entry points to a non-existent location: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-reflect.jar
Error:(5, 5) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: println
Error:(4, 17) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: Array
```

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrJSQ.png) image should explain more.
i should explain that `IDEA` installed  in `D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1` and not `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3` and when I copy `Kotlin` folder from `plugins` folder from installation directory and copy that into `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\plugins` (that i created recently) problem goes away!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the runtime as libraries manually. Only the `kotlin-runtime.jar` is necessary for a beginner.

Comment: this can't be helpful, because IDEA use a directory for that and i should change that directory somehow.

Comment: @SinaDarvishi Have you tried to move the jars into somewhere else(i.e. root of your project) and add them as lib then? Or else you can use gradle to build your project.